# pandas to_excel issue when columns are not null giving index null error

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am writing dataframe to excel, facing issues when columns are are not present (i mean index is none)

Response for each resourcegroup will be like below

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "correlationId": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "eventName": {
                "value": "EndRequest",
                "localizedValue": "EndRequest"
            },
            "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/xxxxxx/extensions/enablevmaccess/events/xxxxxxxxxx/ticks/xxxxxxxx",
            "level": "Informational",
            "resourceGroupName": "xxxxxx",
            "resourceProviderName": {
                "value": "Microsoft.Compute",
                "localizedValue": "Microsoft.Compute"
            },
            "operationName": {
                "value": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/write",
                "localizedValue": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/write"
            },
            "status": {
                "value": "Succeeded",
                "localizedValue": "Succeeded"
            },
            "eventTimestamp": "2020-08-06T12:47:02.0657952Z",
            "submissionTimestamp": "2020-08-06T12:49:03.137537Z"
        },
        {
            "correlationId": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "eventName": {
                "value": "EndRequest",
                "localizedValue": "EndRequest"
            },
            "id": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxx/resourcegroups/xxxxxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/xxxxxx/extensions/enablevmaccess/events/xxxxxxxxxx/ticks/xxxxxxxx",
            "level": "Informational",
            "resourceGroupName": "xxxxxx",
            "resourceProviderName": {
                "value": "Microsoft.Compute",
                "localizedValue": "Microsoft.Compute"
            },
            "operationName": {
                "value": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/write",
                "localizedValue": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions/write"
            },
            "status": {
                "value": "Succeeded",
                "localizedValue": "Succeeded"
            },
            "eventTimestamp": "2020-08-06T12:47:02.0657952Z",
            "submissionTimestamp": "2020-08-06T12:49:03.137537Z"
        },
    ]
}
```

What I am trying is:

```
import pandas
....
for vm_general in vm_list:
    general_view = vm_general.id.split("/")
    resource_group = general_view[4]
    print(resource_group)

    BASE_URL = f"https://xxxxxxxx/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/providers/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2015-04-01&$filter=eventTimestamp ge {start_date} and eventTimestamp le {today} and resourceGroupName eq {resource_group}"
    BASE_URL = BASE_URL
    headers = {
        "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + credential.token["access_token"]
    }
    data = requests.get(BASE_URL, headers=headers)
    dataval = demjson.decode(data.text)
    df = pd.json_normalize(dataval['value'])
    #print(df.columns)    
    cols = ["correlationId","eventName.value","id","resourceGroupName","resourceProviderName.value","operationName.value","status.value","eventTimestamp","submissionTimestamp"]
    #[df.rename(columns={c:'Missing'}, inplace=True) for c in cols if cols.isnull().any()]
    df.fillna('Missing', inplace=True)
    df[cols].to_excel("c:\csv\data2.xls", index=False)
```

Now Problem is at this line for each resource group I am getting some logs and then writing it to excel the below code works only if all resoure group has logs and getting stopped with there is null index (so its writing only few records to excel) and then terminating.

so i tried to mitigate the null cols

```
[df.rename(columns={c:'Missing'}, inplace=True) for c in cols if cols.isnull().any()]
```

but its erroring out saying `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isnull'`

not sure synthatically correct or not. any idea ?

***EDIT 2***: Added sample `response.text` value (how it looks like when i iteraate and print for each resource group)

***EDIT3:***

I used `if not df.empty:` to get rid of empty df, but its printing only last df, i wanted to either merge all df into one then write or  append each df to excel one by one , can some one help me how to achieve it ?

```
for vm_general in vm_list:
    general_view = vm_general.id.split("/")
    resource_group = general_view[4]
    print(resource_group)

    BASE_URL = f"https://xxxxxxxx/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/providers/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2015-04-01&$filter=eventTimestamp ge {start_date} and eventTimestamp le {today} and resourceGroupName eq {resource_group}"
    BASE_URL = BASE_URL
    headers = {
        "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + credential.token["access_token"]
    }
    data = requests.get(BASE_URL, headers=headers)
    dataval = demjson.decode(data.text)
    df = pd.json_normalize(dataval['value'])
    if not df.empty:  
        cols = ["correlationId","eventName.value","id","resourceGroupName","resourceProviderName.value","operationName.value","status.value","eventTimestamp","submissionTimestamp"]    
        df.fillna('Missing', inplace=True)
        df[cols].to_excel("c:\csv\data2.xls", index=False)
```

***EDIT 4***: I am almost nearing solution, I kept writer outside loop , inside loop writeen a statement append df to list, then concatnate outside loop, writing to excel. but no error, but its not writing to excel..

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('c:\csv\data2.xls', engine='xlsxwriter')
df_list = list()
for vm_general in vm_list:
    general_view = vm_general.id.split("/")
    resource_group = general_view[4]
    print(resource_group)

    BASE_URL = f"https://xxxxxxxx/subscriptions/{subscription_id}/providers/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2015-04-01&$filter=eventTimestamp ge {start_date} and eventTimestamp le {today} and resourceGroupName eq {resource_group}"
    BASE_URL = BASE_URL
    headers = {
        "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + credential.token["access_token"]
    }
    data = requests.get(BASE_URL, headers=headers)
    dataval = demjson.decode(data.text)
    df = pd.json_normalize(dataval['value'])
    if not df.empty:  
        cols = ["correlationId","eventName.value","id","resourceGroupName","resourceProviderName.value","operationName.value","status.value","eventTimestamp","submissionTimestamp"]    
        df.fillna('Missing', inplace=True)
        df_list.append(df)

appended_data = pd.concat(df_list)
appended_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Comment: are you trying to rename all the cols have missing value to `Missing` ?

Comment: no , actually i am getting error `KeyError: "None of [Index(['correlationId', 'eventName.value', 'id', 'resourceGroupName',\n       'resourceProviderName.value', 'operationName.value', 'status.value',\n       'eventTimestamp', 'submissionTimestamp'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"` so to handle this i am using above

Comment: to handle that, you simply do `df = df.drop(cols, axis=1)`

Comment: that means, if column values are null, will `df = df.drop(cols, axis=1)` will this handle ?

Comment: @YOLO tried your suggestion  getting `raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['correlationId', 'eventName.value', 'id', 'resourceGroupName',\n       'resourceProviderName.value', 'operationName.value', 'status.value',\n       'eventTimestamp', 'submissionTimestamp'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`  so how can i handle if cols are null, still i want to proceed for next in loop for other iterable items

Comment: The error in your original post is due to the fact that you are performing the `isnull()` operation not on the actual df columns but on the list of strings that you have defined as `cols`. The error you posted in the comments suggest that you don't get any data back at all on some requests? What is `df` if you print it?

Comment: The error you posted in the comments suggest that you don't get any data back at all on some requests?  -- Correct  and when ever there is no data for parituclar resourcegroup response df is printing is like `Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []` so all my struggle is to handle these empty dataframes, and proceed with loop for those resource group which have value and finally i need to write these datafrems to excel one by one by appending or merge all dataframes into one then sigle write to excel

Comment: Ok last some relief, now I used `if not df.empty:` now i got rid of empty df, but only last df is being writtned to excel, How can I append one by one ? I guess to_excel function allows append mode ?

Comment: @HåkanSvensson updated question and my further trails, can you please help

Comment: Either you need to rename the Excel file for each loop, and in this case you'll end up with one file for each iteration of the loop, or you can append the dataframe for each iteration to a list, and then outside the loop concat them and write to file. See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623508/exporting-dataframe-to-excel-using-pandas-without-subscribe/62624110#62624110)

Comment: @HåkanSvensson tried your solution, kept writer outside loop, append inside loop, then concat and write to excel, but no error, but writing not happening (please see my updated code tried in EDIT 4 in main post

Comment: I havent been using the `ExcelWriter` class myself so I have no experience, but why not just try `appended_data.to_excel(r'c:\csv\data2.xlsx')` ?

Comment: At last it worked. i just did like you did....thanks a lot